# How to pass Generic Type to tap pipe in Angular Observable

Tags: angular, generics, rxjs, typescript-generics

I have an angular directive like so:

```js
@Input('getData') getData!: <T>() => Observable<T>;

...

preloadData(): void {
  this.getData()
    .pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        if (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      }),
      take(1)
    )
    .subscribe();
}

...
```

and my **getData** could be any type, post in this example:

```js
getData(): Observable<Post> {
  return this.getPost();
}
```

I am getting errors in Visual Studio:

[image]

How do I correctly implement a generic type inside the **tap** operator here?

J

Comment: The `preloadData()` function needs to be defined as generic as well. `preloadData<T>()`

Comment: Lol, that fixed it, pretty simple, thanks!